# Erro aplicação utilizando vetor java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, array

Bom dia.

Estou tentando realizar um exercício proposto em um curso de Java que estou fazendo porém não estou conseguindo. Trata-se de um programa simples que simula a reserva de um *hostel* utilizando vetores.

Preciso que, após selecionar a quantidade de quartos que serão reservados, o programa solicite o nome do cliente(*Student*).

Entretanto quando eu executo o programa e digito o nome do cliente ele aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.Program.main(Program.java:25)
```

Acredito que o erro esteja dentro do bloco `for` no trecho `s[i].setName(n);` da classe *Main*

Porém não consegui resolver.

Abaixo estão os códigos(classes *Program*, *Hostel* e *Student* que estou usando nesse projeto Java:

```
package application;

import java.util.Scanner;

import entities.Hostel;
import entities.Student;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hostel h[];
        h = new Hostel[10];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many rooms will be rented?: ");
        int room = sc.nextInt();
        Student[] s = new Student[room];
        sc.nextLine();

        for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("RENT #"+i);
            System.out.print("Name :");
            String n = sc.nextLine();
            s[i].setName(n);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}

package entities;

public class Hostel {
    private int room;
    private char situation;


    public int getRoom() {
        return room;
    }
    public void setRoom(int room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
    public char getSituation() {
        return situation;
    }
    public void setSituation(char situation) {
        this.situation = situation;
    }


}

package entities;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Student(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique o ponteiro nulo na linha 25. É apenas isso.

Você precisa instanciar a variável `s`, tipo:

```
s[i] = new Student();
```

Lembre-se que na sua classe `Student` não existe um construtor sem os parâmetros, é importante criar lá.

Exemplo:

```
public Student(){
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hostel h[];
    h = new Hostel[10];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many rooms will be rented?: ");
    int room = sc.nextInt();
    Student[] s = new Student[room];
    sc.nextLine();

    for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("RENT #"+i);
        System.out.print("Name :");
        String n = sc.nextLine();
        s[i] = new Student();
        s[i].setName(n);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Você pode usar o Debug para confirmar quais dos dois índices estão nulos. É bastante simples. Qualquer dúvida, estamos aí p/ ajudar.

Comment: Filipe, obrigado pelo retorno.
Alterei o código conforme sua orientação, mas mesmo assim estou com dúvida.
Veja o código abaixo:
  
  System.out.print("How many rooms will be rented?: ");
  int room = sc.nextInt();
  Student s;
  sc.nextLine();
  
  for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("RENT #"+i);
   System.out.print("Name :");
   String name = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Email :");
   String email = sc.nextLine();
   s[i] = new Student(name, email);
  }
  sc.close();

Comment: Bom, mas você tem um objeto vazio que é o "Student s". Não há nada nele, então vai dar erro. Não foi da forma como coloquei, dê uma olhada com mais carinho hehe :)

Comment: Ok, seu código funcionou da maneira que propôs. 
Mas se eu fosse utilizar um método construtor passando os parâmetros de nome e e-mail? Como seria?
`
 System.out.print("How many rooms will be rented?: ");
  int room = sc.nextInt();
  sc.nextLine();
  Student s[];
  
  for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++) {
   System.out.println("RENT #"+i);
   System.out.print("Name :");
   String name = sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Email :");
   String email = sc.nextLine();
   s[i] = new Student(name, email);
  }
`

Comment: Só gostaria de entender o motivo pelo qual algum cidadão negativou a minha resposta, sendo que o objetivo foi apenas ajudar. Ao invés de negativar, poderia propor uma resposta melhor.

Comment: Douglas, basta instanciar com os parâmetros.. new Student("Nome da pessoa", "email@dapessoa.com");

Comment: É tchê, e quem disse que só tem cavalheiros na Inglaterra?  Votos downs são aplicados 90% por operadores(moderadores idem) que nem respondem a pergunta onde os aplicaram, e na grande maioria, por razões fúteis, e isso opera independente que o código funcione ou não, mas, pior até, também há os que votam up, por razões igualmente fúteis, e em muitos códigos que nem funcionam, que nem testaram e que nem o farão. É lamentável, mas é um fato. Eu acho q o down só poderia ser aplicado mediante um comentário.